# Locking a table and disabling the indexes hangs mysql - 100% CPU

Tags: mysql, locking

```
CREATE TABLE `runs` (
  `RunID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`RunID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `runs`
--
-- WHERE:  runid=430864838

LOCK TABLES `runs` WRITE;
ALTER TABLE `runs` DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO `runs` VALUES (430864838);
```

As soon as `` ALTER TABLE `runs` DISABLE KEYS; `` runs it seems to hang the database - a core is 100% being used and it will not respond.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Potentially it's this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60563

Comment: Don't use `LOCK TABLES` on InnoDB tables.  Is `mysqldump` doing this?  Which version?`

Answer (score 0):

I switched over to Mariadb and successfully ran the query.